# Multiple maven dependencies using multiple version numbers

Tags: javascript, maven, build-dependencies

I'm trying to prototype using Maven with a JavaScript application. Our use case however, is making me wonder whether what we need is actually possible.

We have a common library (lib-a) with a dependency on version 1.1 of a core library (core-1.1) specified within its POM. We then have an application that uses lib-a, but uses version 1.2 of the core library. lib-a will still need to use 1.1 because it is a tested/released/approved library that we are happy is stable and doesn't have need for a re-release at this point in time.

In our application POM we reference lib-a and core-1.2; then calling `mvn clean verify` would expect/hope we get the following app structure:

> app/
>
> > src/
> >
> > target/
> >
> > > lib-a/
> > >
> > > core-1.1/
> > >
> > > core-1.2/

Though the debug logs show

> core:zip:1.1:compile (removed - nearer found: 1.2)

I understand it would want to do that in the Java world, is there a way to stop it removing the older version for our case?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that `lib-a` contains a method `m` that takes an argument of type `x` that is defined in `core`. If the application calls `m` it would use `core-1.2`'s version of type `x`, while the method `m` is designed to receive `core-1.1`'s version of type `x`. Depending on the changes to `x` between `core-1.1` and `core-1.2` this may be sufficiently incompatible to not work.

What you describe is a common struggle within Maven. And I can only imagine that without Maven the struggle is the same, as it is an inherent problem with what you're trying to do. Without proper dependency management the results may actually be more sneaky and subtle -- even though Maven's almost silent debug log statement isn't too explicit either. (You could build stronger checks into your Maven lifecycle, though.)

There is many useful open source libraries that depend on other open source libraries which you in turn also want to depend on yourself, hence giving you the same problem, or at least the same responsibility to make sure it's all using the same libraries or otherwise make sure that it happily works together.

Maven lets you use the "wrong" version of a dependency (whatever that means), but it won't let you use two different versions of the same dependency.

Bottom line, rethink what you are doing here, as you're headed to getting burned. One way to rethink may be to split up `core` such that you don't (or less often) need to re-release `lib-a` when there's changes to (what you currently call) `core` that are only for the benefit of the dependent application.

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for your comments. Appreciate what you're saying, and would understand that this could cause issues in some instances. In our environment however we will be using alias's to map which version of core-1.* to use against the app and lib-a. That way there will not be any cross-over in method/argument calls.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by aliases? What technology is that a concept of?

Comment: We're actually using Dojo, which allows us to set up path aliases so that we can manage the dependencies.

Comment: That sounds as if you're going to build `lib-a` using `core-1.1`, deploy it with `core-1.1` in the file system, but then have it use `core-1.2` (due to how you set up the [aliases](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#alias-modules)). It seems somewhat unlikely to me that you can avoid the underlying conflict that I described. Things might be slightly better if there's no API changes between 1.1 and 1.2, but since you seem to be loading everything into the same execution space, it seems unlikely that 1.1 and 1.2 can actually live together, so you will still feel the pain.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen the solution being discussed here is using JavaScript code and the imports can be very specific when requiring modules using dojo. Therefore you can in theory use multiple versions of the 'core' library even in the same class! Thats where the complication comes, its all possible until you come to package and build and the technology (in this case Maven) makes a predetermined choice for the user not to allow multiple versions of the same library. A philosophy I would agree with usually but not in this case.